# How do I warm up my flash's color for indoor shooting with slide film?

Tags: flash, white-balance, color-correction, 35mm, slides

I am using ISO 100 35mm slide film (camera Minolta x700, with a dedicated flash unit). Pictures taken indoors with flash have come out insipid and almost too cold (white).

How can I add a bit of yellow or orange or basically warmer tone? Would bounce flash help (even though the ceiling is also white)? If yes, would I need exposure compensation?

Comment: What specific film were you using? For what color temperature is it balanced?

Comment: Related: [For a novice to flash, what color correction gels would be best to experiment with?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/16991/11924)

Comment: I used the Agfa Precia CT 100 Slide film

Answer (score 3):

Put a gel filter over your flash. Golden or orange (especially the CTO) will be best. These filters are available from various manufacturers and holders are also available,if you desire one. There is a product from Rosco that includes variety of pre-cut filters for this purpose that includes various effect colors, but also balancing ones. It is called [The Strobist Collection.](http://www.rosco.com/filters/flashpack_strobist.cfm)

Answer (score 0):

There are warming and cooling filters that can be mounted atop the lens. The warming series is 81A – 81B – 81C – 81D. These are pale salmon, 81D being the strongest. All require you to increase exposure 1/3 stop. Alternately, you can warm up the flash with gel filters. Gels are likely your best bet as they are available from theatrical supply houses as they are used to alter the colors of stage lighting.

Let me add that electronic flash is generally a good match for daylight balanced slide film. It is highly likely that the cool results are due to improper processing at the lab. Should you apply warming filters base on this one experience, next time your results may be too warm.

Comment: Considering that the OP states the pictures were taken indoors it may well be that the slide film was balanced for tungsten light.

Comment: I used the Agfa Precia CT 100 Slide film